# Possible to record user inputted console commands on the client side?

Tags: javascript, console, client

Is it at all feasible to somehow record any commands inputted client side by way of the js console in the inspector?

I was just thinking about this and couldn't find any info. My gut feeling would be "no" BUT, i wonder if it's at all possible to add some kind of listener that's not just a key logger.

Comment: Could you add more information on why you would want to that ?

Comment: Technically, the console calls the current Javascript context, so you could register function call after the page has load, but that's far fetch.

Comment: Pure curiosity. I didn’t have a specific use case in mine.